# Error with Ant build when transferring NetBeans project from Windows to Linux VM

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, ant

I have a large NetBeans project that requires a fair amount of time to complete computations, so I've been trying to transition it to a Linux box hosted on Azure, so that I can SSH in, run the commands I need, and not have to worry about it occupying my desktop resources at home.

I've deployed using git, so all of the files matchup, excluding a few .properties files that are specific to the directory structure on my desktop (which I've adjusted for the Linux box), but I'm hitting an error whenever I run the build using ant.

`ant -f ~/My/Project/Structure/ -Dnb.internal.action.name=run run`

is the command I run, but it's faced with a `"nbproject/build-impl.xml:800: ... is not a valid directory"`. The problem is, it's somehow concatenating the new, Linux directory structure with the previous Windows structure when I try to build it. It's doing something similar to:

`/home/UserName/My/Project/Structure/D:/Development/GitHub/My/Project/Structure`

But I can't find where in the ant build it is still referencing the previous directory structure. On line 800 of `build-impl.xml` is the following

`<java classname="@{classname}" dir="${work.dir}" fork="true">`

but it's not evident where the variable `${work.dir}` is defined. What's also interesting is that this is the final reference to this variable in the .xml file. Every other reference is prior to this, so it's strange that none of the earlier references throw an error but this one does.

Any ideas?

Comment: Change directories to the `~/My/Project/Structure/` and run ant from within that context.  Alternatively, if you're not modifying the code on the remote box, you should just build the project on your desktop and export the jar's to the remote box instead

Comment: Exporting the jar and other essential files seems to work fine, although the jar is 16MB so it's a pain to reupload so often

Answer (score 0):

Just for comparison in my projects:

work.dir is set on line 148 of build-impl.xml with

```
<property name="work.dir" value="${basedir}"/>
```

basedir is set near the top build-impl.xml in project open tag

```
<project xmlns:j2seproject1="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/j2se-project/1" xmlns:j2seproject3="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/j2se-project/3" xmlns:jaxrpc="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/j2se-project/jax-rpc" basedir=".." default="default" name="JavaApplication26-impl">
```